# CTRL+SHIFT+U is not opening Wave tool with Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, awtrobot

I tried opening Wave tool extension via different codes but it's not working. Here are all the things that I tried:

`Robot rb=new Robot();`

Option 1:

```
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.delay(100);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
rb.delay(100);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);`

//close
rb.delay(100);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
rb.delay(100);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
rb.delay(100);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Option 2:

`action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("u").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();`

Earlier I used to open it with the 'right-click' process

`

```
    action.contextClick().build().perform();

Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);


robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
`
```

But now I'm trying to switch to the shortcut keys(CONTROL+SHIFT+U).Can somebody please help me out. Tried this on Chrome.

Comment: Please include textual content (code, error message, ...) always as `formatted` text in your question description. Content of images cannot be searched; see also [other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698098). As a new contributor – _Welcom to Stack Overflow_ – you may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CTRL+SHIFT+U is not opening Wave tool with Java Selenium. Can someone suggest a better option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167367/ctrlshiftu-is-not-opening-wave-tool-with-java-selenium-can-someone-suggest-a)

Comment: @RichEdwards That question has been deleted. Anyway I had added the extension using the following code:

 `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
  
  options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\chromedriver\\wavew.crx"));

  options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
  driver=new ChromeDriver(options)`

Comment: And earlier I was opening the Wave tool using the Robot class. Just wanted to make changes to it and open it via the shortcut keys (CONTROL+SHIFT+U)

Comment: code used earlier to launch wave tool:

`action.contextClick().build().perform();
   Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);  
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

Comment: You deleted the post with an answer to create a new one with the same content? ... If that answer could have helped someone else that's now gone... - as per the answer in the previous post that no one will see - have opened the link in chromedriver instance to confirm the your wave extension is present?  - can you please also edit your question to add code with some context as opposed to massive text blocks in comments....

Comment: When you say "code used earlier" are you saying you used to have the working code to open the extension and that now stopped working?

Comment: Sorry I'm not totally familiar with this website.I'll edit the question. And by 'code used earlier' I meant that I was using the above method earlier but wanted to switch to 'control+Shift+U' method. I have written the code for the shortcut keys but it doesn't seem to work. @RichEdwards

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It's not proper but it works out for me. We can directly open the extension shortcut window , assign the shortcut keys(I have assigned 'CONTROL+I'),navigate to our website and open 'WAVE tool' using the robot class.

```
// setup key shourtcut for extension
        driver.navigate().to("chrome://extensions/shortcuts");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Hope this helps out others.